# Will the Palm Pre Mojo SDK grant access to bluetooth apis?

Tags: webos, palm-pre, mojo-sdk

Does anyone know if Palm's new Mojo SDK will grant access to bluetooth APIs? Perhaps in some form or fashion? I can't get any information about it and given I have to choose what to spend my money on in regards to the the next platform for my development, I would really like to NOT waste it.

Perhaps there's some lucky PRE developmers out there who already know the answer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, there's no access to the Bluetooth stack from the webOS APIs.  It's possible that future versions of the system could expose them, but there's no system service for doing things like BT file transport.  Currently Bluetooht is only supported for voice, A2DP playback, and AVRCP remote controls.